# How to boost Solr document score based on field value?

Tags: solr, typo3-9.x

We are using solr in the context of typo3 so most of the configuration happens within typoscript. What we try is to set a boost for documents based on the value of a specific field of that document.

So we index something like `customBoost_intS = 10` (we thought about -10 ... 10) and when we query for documents I thought about

```
boostQuery = if(termfreq(customBoost_intS,"-10"),-10,if(termfreq(customBoost_intS,"-9"),-9,0))
```

But that would result in a very long configuration to go from negative 10 to positive 10... isn't there a solution to use the actual field value as a document boost? So we could just limit the input for that field.

help is much appreciated

Comment: There are multiple ways of doing that - just `&boost=customBoost_intS` should work with the edismax query parser. Have you seen the wiki entry for [How can I change the score of a document based on the *value* of a field (say, "popularity")](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#SolrRelevancyFAQ-HowcanIchangethescoreofadocumentbasedonthe*value*ofafield\(say,%22popularity%22\))? It's slightly outdated (as it doesn't consider the `boost` argument added with edismax, but it will give you several ways for other query parsers)